# How to return an array from a function with Fish Shell

Tags: fish

I am trying to return an array from a function. The code below doesn't work.

```
function testArray
   echo 1 2 3 4
end

set r (testArray)

echo $r[2]
# error
```

What is the proper way to return multiple values from a function using fish shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained by [ridiculous_fish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19844198/802365) you can use native line-splitting mechanism.

> result of a command substitution becomes a list by splitting on newlines (`$IFS`)

So

1. list one item per line ;
2. then capture that in a command substitution.

#### Listing

```
function __list_public_keys
    for key in ~/.ssh/*.pub
        echo $key
    end
end
```

output

```
$ __list_public_keys
/home/ed8/.ssh/id_rsa.blabla.pub
/home/ed8/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
/home/ed8/.ssh/id_rsa.test.pub
```

#### Capturing

```
function __add_keys
    set keys (__list_public_keys)

    echo "[" $keys "]"
end
```

output

```
$ __add_keys
[/home/ed8/.ssh/id_rsa.blabla.pub] [/home/ed8/.ssh/id_rsa.pub] [/home/ed8/.ssh/id_rsa.test.pub]
```

Answer (score 13):

The result of a command substitution becomes a list by splitting on newlines (technically the contents of `$IFS`, but modifying IFS is discouraged).

So you could replace spaces with newlines, perhaps with `tr`:

```
function testArray
   echo 1 2 3 4
end
set r (testArray | tr ' ' \n)
echo $r[2]
```

Or modify the function to just output newlines directly:

```
function testArray
   echo \n1\n2\n3\n4
end
set r (testArray)
echo $r[2]
```

https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/445 tracks better mechanisms for generating lists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible yet. Compare this [issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/441) on GitHub.